# Functioning of memset

Tags: c++, memset

I have read in some places that memset writes "byte-wise".

Suppose I have an array, `int a[100]` and I use `memset(a,127,sizeof(a));` , will every byte of every integer be assigned the bitset `1111111` ?

That is, will every element of the array now hold a very large integer? (`2139062143` to be exact)

Comment: `memset` isn't incredibly useful for filling with other than just zeros, though, except maybe for byte-size data. It's rare that a nonzero value when repeated becomes a useful value.

Comment: Note that the value of an integer composed entirely of bits-set-to-one can vary depending on what kind of computer you are running the code on.

Comment: @Jeremy: not all bits are set to zero, as 127 is represented by 0111'1111 (as stated correctly by Rayu). I don't know, whether that is still platform dependent in theory, but any platform I know of - that has 32bit integers - will interprete this the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you correct the third parameter of `memset()` into

```
memset(a, 127, sizeof(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void* memset( void* dest, int ch, std::size_t count );
```

Converts the value ch to unsigned char and copies it into each of the first count characters of the object pointed to by dest. If the object is not trivially-copyable (e.g., scalar, array, or a C-compatible struct), the behavior is undefined. If count is greater than the size of the object pointed to by dest, the behavior is undefined.

So, yes every byte would be assigned 111...